# openface How to import person pictures and compare any picture later on

Tags: comparison, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to understand [openface](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface).
I have installed the docker container, run the demos and read the docks.
What I am missing is, how to start using it correctly.

Let me explain to you my goals:

I have an app on a raspberry pi with a webcam. If I start the app it will take a picture of the person infront.
Now it should send this picture to my openface app and check, if the face is known. *Known* in this context means, that I already added pictures of this person to openface before.

My questions are:

- Do I need to train openface before, or could I just put the images of the persons in a directory or s.th. and compare the webcam picture on the fly with these directories?
- Do I compare with images or with a generated .pkl?
- Do I need to *train* openface for each new person?

It feels like I am missing a big thing that makes the required workflow clearer to me.

Comment: I just found what looks like a great tutorial for beginners in this particular topic: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record: With help of the [link I mentioned](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78) I could figure it out somehow.

***Do I need to train openface before, or could I just put the images of the persons in a directory or s.th. and compare the webcam picture on the fly with these directories?***

Yes, a training is required in order to compare any images.

***Do I compare with images or with a generated .pkl?***

Images are compared with the generated classifier pkl.
The pkl file gets generated when training openface:

```
./demos/classifier.py train ./generated-embeddings/
```

This will generate a new file called ./generated-embeddings/classifier.pkl. This file has the SVM model you'll use to recognize new faces.

***Do I need to train openface for each new person?***

OK, for this question I don't have an answer yet. But just because I did not look deeper into this topic yet.